# Python parser for differential equations: syntax errors with ast and sympify

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, sympy, ode

I'm trying to parse (ordinary) differential equations. Ideally, I'd prefer to use an existing parser - otherwise, this leads directly to things like grammars and is likely fairly laborious.

Edit: The idea is to then feed the equation to SymPy's solvers and integrators, and do some stuff with it that's irrelevant to the question.

I have found this [list](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html) of custom parsers, but it seems to be somewhat outdated and doesn't seem to mention what I'm looking for directly.

So far, I've tried **ast** (which uses compile(), I think) and **sympify**, without success:

```
lagrangeODE = '''f''(x) + f'(x) + f(x)'''

import ast
tree = ast.parse(lagrangeODE)
```

produces

```
tree = ast.parse(lagrangeODE)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    f''(x) + f'(x) + f(x)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

while

```
import sympy as sy
expr = sy.sympify(lagrangeODE)
```

produces

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse "f''(x) + f'(x) + f(x)"' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

To me, this basically means that ast and sympify don't understand Langrangian notations of ODEs.

Please advise:

1. Am I using ast and sympify wrong, or are they not suitable for the
   task?
2. Is there another existing way, or should I implement one
   myself?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @zondo Edited to include that in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ast` module is designed to parse Python. Your input is not Python. Similarly, `sympify` is designed to parse strings that look like SymPy syntax, and `'` is not SymPy syntax. Neither tool is appropriate for your task.

Get a general-purpose parser generator and write a grammar. [`pyparsing`](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) would be one choice.